# Awarding bounty greater than reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I was looking at the userpage for [insert-here-the-user-who-shall-not-be-named] who recently offered a bounty of 150 on a question and seemed to have a reputation of just 16. I was curious what made somebody quite so generous / desperate for a good answer to a question.

In recent reputation changes I noticed a -150 for awarding a bounty and a +99 "rep change". Looking at the reputation history since then, it appears that the award of a 150 rep bounty caused the account to go overdrawn, and it got "rebalanced" to 1.

That leads to my question: under what circumstances can one offer a bounty that exceeds ones reputation? Is there a limit?

Comment: It may have had something to do with [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234279/about-rep-changes-and-gaming-system-using-them), but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: @davidZ interesting link. I had not seen this, not heard of the exploit. It is possible that you are right. I can't look at a user's delete/undelete history (maybe I can and don't know it) to confirm your hunch.

Comment: Not that I condone hacking the SE system of course, but I take my hat off to whoever spotted that loophole :-)

Answer (score 2):

Moderators are not allowed to comment on specific cases due to privacy concerns, but let me say in general that missing reputation is often associated with:

1. deleted user accounts.
2. deleted posts.
3. invalidated reputation due to voting irregularities (read: [sock puppetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sock_puppetry)).

Note that gaming the reputation system may in general lead to suspension (if that wasn't obvious).